# Facebook Marketing API - Adset Creation with Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, google-apps-script

I am using *Facebook graph API* to create a *Facebook ads* campaign from *Google Apps Script*.

I successfully create a Campaign, I get the ID of this new campaign and then I try to create an adset associated with it, but I get the following error:

```
Exception: Request failed for https://graph.facebook.com returned code 400. Truncated server response: {"error":{"message":"Invalid parameter","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"error_subcode":1815430,"is_transient":false,"error_user_title":"Nessun ... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)
    at createAdsets(Create:309:36)
```

The facebook Url I encode and then fetch is:

> `https://graph.facebook.com/v7.0/act_XXX/adsets?name=BlaBla&daily_budget=5000&campaign_id=YYY&bid_strategy=LOWEST_COST_WITHOUT_CAP&billing_event=IMPRESSIONS&optimization_goal=LEAD_GENERATION&targeting={"age_max":65,"age_min":25,"geo_locations":{"countries":["IT"],"location_types":["home","recent"]},"targeting_optimization":"expansion_all","brand_safety_content_filter_levels":["FACEBOOK_STANDARD"]}&status=PAUSED&access_token=ZZZ`

Do you see any mistake in this UTL?
If not, can you help me see the full Truncated server response, especially the "error_user_title"?

In order to do that I have already tried:

1. To pass the **muteHttpExceptions: true** as options, but I only get the full response without being able to examine the error
2. To use the stackdriver with **console.error** method, but the "error" remains truncated.

Comment: What do you mean by _“but I only get the full response without being able to examine the error”_?

Comment: If the Google Apps Script environment is giving you trouble getting at a proper error message … then try the request somewhere else first? F.e. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ exists to assist testing Graph API requests.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @CBroe! I tried the Graph API explorer tool and now I am able to read the full error. However, I am not able to solve it, because the error message says that I didn't accept the conditions for lead generations on my facebook page. I have already done that, but I keep getting the same error. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I managed to solve the problem! I had to add 2 new permissions, leads_retrieval and pages_manage_ads, in the Graph API explorer tool and generate a new token. Now the code is working! Thank you @CBroe